# Python ebay-sdk: how to change currency

Tags: python, python-3.x, ebay-api

I am using https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python to connect to ebay api.

I want to list an item on the uk version of ebay, using the token i created there.
All api calls is changed from .com to .co.uk.
I have changed the currency from USD to GBP, but it seems that USD is the only accepted currency.

I am running everything in a sandbox.

Any idea how to fix my issue?

**The Code:**

```
try:

    api = Trading(config_file=None, domain='api.sandbox.ebay.com',
                  appid=S.EBAY_SANDBOX_APPID, devid=S.EBAY_SANDBOX_DEVID,
                  certid=S.EBAY_SANDBOX_CERTID, token=acc.token)

    myitem = {
        "Item": {
            "Title": item.nazwa,
            "Description": "<![CDATA[{}]]>".format(item.desc),
            "PrimaryCategory": {"CategoryID": "377"},
            "StartPrice": str(round(item.price.amount, 2)),
            "CategoryMappingAllowed": "true",
            "Country": "GB",
            "ConditionID": "3000",
            "Currency": "GBP",
            "DispatchTimeMax": "3",
            "ListingDuration": "Days_{}".format(str(item.len)),
            "ListingType": "FixedPriceItem",
            "PaymentMethods": "PayPal",
            "PayPalEmailAddress": "abc@mail.com",
            "PictureDetails": {"PictureURL": "http://i1.sandbox.ebayimg.com/03/i/00/30/07/20_1.JPG?set_id=8800005007"},
            "PostalCode": "BH104HS",
            "Quantity": str(round(item.qty, 0)),
            "ReturnPolicy": {
                "ReturnsAcceptedOption": "ReturnsAccepted",
                "RefundOption": "MoneyBack",
                "ReturnsWithinOption": "Days_30",
                "Description": "If you are not satisfied, return the goods for refund.",
                "ShippingCostPaidByOption": "Buyer"
            },
            "ShippingDetails": {
                "ShippingType": "Flat",
                "ShippingServiceOptions": {
                    "ShippingServicePriority": "1",
                    "ShippingService": "USPSMedia",
                    "ShippingServiceCost": "4.50"
                }
            },
            "Site": 'UK'
        }
    }
    api.execute('AddFixedPriceItem', myitem)
    print(api)
    dump(api, True)

except ConnectionError as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.response.dict())
```

**The response:**

```
AddFixedPriceItem: Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 95, Invalid auction currency. The auction currency specified does not match the auction currency for the selected site.' {'Errors': {'ErrorCode': '95', 'ShortMessage': 'Invalid auction currency.', 'SeverityCode': 'Error', 'ErrorClassification': 'RequestError', 'LongMessage': 'The auction currency specified does not match the auction currency for the selected site.'}, 'Build': 'E1031_UNI_API5_18532394_R1', 'Ack': 'Failure', 'Timestamp': '2017-09-25T18:48:34.353Z', 'Version': '1031'}
```

Answer (score 0):

in line 3, youre gonna want to change your domain from ebay US to UK. i think whats happening is you are sending a dictionary asking for UK data, but you're sending that request to the US site.

go from this

```
domain='api.sandbox.ebay.com'
```

to this

```
domain='sandbox.ebay.co.uk'
```

i would like to think that im confident about my answer to your problem, but its possible that this is not the correct link itself. if you look in your developers account you should be able to see the link for your country.